# Which method is better for checking if a user is logged into website in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Which is a better method for checking if one of my users is logged into the site?

First method - in the controller I can get the id and if it's null, then there is no user logged in

```
User.Identity.GetUserId() // if null , then no user is logged in
```

Second method - in the controller or in my service layer

```
bool isLoggedIn = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) 
     && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

is one method better then the other or does it really matter?

Comment: They are both doing basically the same thing. Well, one is checking `GetUserId` and the other is `IsAuthenticated` - but other than that the same. I'd lean to always use `IsAuthenticated` for consistency.

Comment: asp.net mvc with .net framework

Answer (score 1):

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is the default way of checking. the bool is designed for this check. you shouldn't need anything else such as `User != null` as long as your authentication is done right.

Comment: Is `IHttpContextAccessor` a ASP.NET Core only thing?

Comment: in a manner of speaking yep. But it is a part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` package which uses .net standard.  So it can be used in .net framework as well as long as it has the sdk. Regardless that isn't really a part of the answer. just an additional tip.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext` => ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Core. Everything after "You can also..." is irrelevant to the question

Comment: true. just noticed later it was .net framework. however as i said. `IHttpContextAccessor` would still work with SDKs

Comment: It's not a matter of .NET Framework vs .NET Core, but the fact that ASP.NET Core data is not available in an ASP.NET context. It would *compile*, but it wouldn't work. The exact same would hold true if you wanted to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET Core application targeting .NET Framework. It will compile, but it won't work.